# How to Draw a Plot in R Which is Not a Box-and-Whiskers Plot

Tags: r, plot, dataset

I have a large data set which has data like below:

```
      Age          Ethnicity          Gender        Crude_Rate 
      20-24        Pacific Islander   Female        39.2   
      55-59        Caucasian          Male          100.3
      60-64        African            Female        3.2
      30-34        Asian              Male          2.8
```

I am trying to draw three plots on R for:

- crude rate (y-axis always) against age
- crude rate against ethnicity
- crude rate against gender

I am getting plots but it is a box-and-whisker plot with points above it which is not what I want. I would just like the points to be plotted i.e. a scatter plot.

The code I am using is:

```
melanoma <-read.csv("Melanoma Age.csv", header=TRUE, na.strings = c("Not     Applicable"))
melanoma<-na.omit(melanoma)


plot(melanoma$Gender, melanoma$Crude_Rate,las=2, ylab="Crude Rate",    xlab="Gender", main="Crude Rates for Both Genders")
plot(melanoma$Age, melanoma$Crude_Rate,las=2, ylab="Crude Rate", main="Crude Rates for Different Age Groups")
plot(melanoma$Ethnicity, melanoma$Crude_Rate,las=2, ylab="Crude Rate", main="Crude Rates for Different Ethnicities")
```

I don't get what I have done wrong because usually when I do this I get a scatter plot, not a box-and-whisker plot with points above it.

Thank you in advanced for any help

Comment: R tends to draw a boxplot when y is a factor. If you need a scatter plot, try plotting without an y axis but specifying different colors or point shapes, i.e. using smth like `plot(melanoma$Crude_Rate, col = melanoma$Gender, ...)` where ... stands for any other plotting params. Another suggestion would be to use subsets of the data and plot them on different diagrams.

Comment: @ Dmitry Grekov Thank you, I tried plot(melanoma$Crude_Rate, col = melanoma$Gender) and now I am getting a scatter plot, but unfortunately x-axis labels are numbers not female and male.

Comment: the veritcal axis is now for Crude_Rate and the horizontal label is just the index of the observation. You may use `legend()` to specify which gender is plotted with certain color.

Comment: That is a nice graph, but unfortunatley the problem is I would like age, gender and ethnicity separately as the horizontal-axis (x-axis) on the three graphs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the car package and the function scatterplot. This will provide you with extras on the graph (eg. box and whiskers and a smoother) but these can be easily removed.

Comment: Thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

If your x values are a factor variable, you can produce a scatter plot like this:

```
#a reproducible example
set.seed(42)
x <- factor(sample(c("A", "B"), 20, TRUE))
y <- rnorm(20)

#use plot.default explicitly to avoid using plot.factor implicitly
plot.default(y ~ x, type = "p", 
             xlim = range(as.integer(unique(x))) + c(-0.4, 0.4), 
             xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = seq_along(levels(x)), labels = levels(x))
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Hi Roland. Thank you for that. Sorry, I am fairly new to R. What would I need to do to change that code for my data?

Comment: `plot.default(Crude_rate ~ Gender, data = melanoma, xlim = range(as.integer(unique(melanoma$Gender))) + c(-0.4, 0.4)...)`

Comment: Thank you, so do I need to add anything after plot.default(Crude_Rate ~ Gender, data = melanoma, 
             xlim = range(as.integer(unique(melanoma$Gender))) + c(-0.4, 0.4))?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to show you how to plot crude rate against age. Similarly you can draw other plots. For simplicity I have shown creation process  step by step

```
input = NULL
input$Age = rep(c("20-24","55-59","60-64","30-34"),4)
input$Crude_Rate = runif(16)
input = as.data.frame(input)

library(dplyr)
Byage <- input %>% 
        group_by(Age) %>% 
        summarise(n = n(), Crude_Rate = mean(Crude_Rate))
plot1 <-ggplot(input, aes(Age, Crude_Rate))
plot1 <-plot1 + geom_jitter(width = 0.5)
plot1 <-plot1 + geom_point(data = Byage, colour = "red", size = 4)
plot1 <-plot1 + geom_text(aes(y = -0.1, label = paste0("n = ", n)), Byage, size = 3)
```

This will generate a nice scatter plot with age group as the x axis and Crude_Rate as the y axis with number of samples in each group at the bottom.

[ScatterPlot of Age vs Crude_Rate with each age group mean Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcGEu.png)

Comment: Thank you for that! Unfortunately I am getting a lot of errors when I am trying.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the errors that you are getting. You need to install and load ggplot2 library to use above code.

Comment: It worked, I just had to make it input$Crude_Rate = runif(361) because I have the categories: input$Age = rep(c("<1", "1-4", "5-9", "10-14", "15-19", "20-24", "25-29", "30-34", "35-39", "40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64", "65-69", "70-74", "75-79", "80-84", "85+"),19). Thank you

Comment: Thanks :) unfortunately because my data set is so large it became a bit messy. Do you know how to make this into a histogram with the crude rates summed?